# Select all members which have visited all courses on a certain day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a query which selects all members which have a 'GOLD' status and also attended all courses which happen on a Sunday.

This would be my select statement:

```
SELECT member_ID, first_name, last_name
FROM member
         JOIN person p on member.fk_person = p.person_ID
         JOIN enrolment e on member.member_ID = e.fk_member_ID
         JOIN membership m on member.fk_membership = m.membership_ID
         JOIN class c on e.fk_class_ID = c.class_ID
WHERE status = 'GOLD'
GROUP BY member_ID, first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class WHERE weekday = 'SUNDAY');
```

This following statements returns two classes which happen on a Sunday:

```
SELECT count(class_id)
FROM class
WHERE weekday = 'SUNDAY';
```

Is my select statement on top so wrong? What should I do to achieve my goal?

The entire SQL script is available here: https://pastebin.com/MtAp2p5k

Comment: Hi, I can help do you have a ER Diagram of your database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're just missing a WHERE predicate to filter only those with class on sundays (so that the count(*) works correctly):

```
SELECT member_ID, first_name, last_name
FROM member
         JOIN person p on member.fk_person = p.person_ID
         JOIN enrolment e on member.member_ID = e.fk_member_ID
         JOIN membership m on member.fk_membership = m.membership_ID
         JOIN class c on e.fk_class_ID = c.class_ID
WHERE status = 'GOLD' AND c.weekday = 'SUNDAY'
GROUP BY member_ID, first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class WHERE weekday = 'SUNDAY');
```

Comment: How is this *any* different from the answer I already posted?

Comment: I started typing before you - there were no answers. Just a parallelism issue. Nothing to bother you, I guess

Answer (score 2):

You need to condition the `COUNT` in the main part of the query so it is also only counting classes on a Sunday:

```
SELECT member_ID, first_name, last_name
FROM member
         JOIN person p on member.fk_person = p.person_ID
         JOIN enrolment e on member.member_ID = e.fk_member_ID
         JOIN membership m on member.fk_membership = m.membership_ID
         JOIN class c on e.fk_class_ID = c.class_ID
WHERE status = 'GOLD' AND weekday = 'SUNDAY'
GROUP BY member_ID, first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class WHERE weekday = 'SUNDAY');
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
member_id   first_name  last_name
1           Peter       Simmler
2           Frances     Simmler
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e72a8c85b99bd445d341b84c8e7e5567)